# why using useRef (initialValue) instead of useMemo()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

As far as I understand, another purpose of useRef(initialValue) is to keep a variable whose reference address does not change whenever a re-render of that component in the function component.

However, the same can be done with useMemo().
What's the difference between the two? which one is more performance.

```
import React, { useState, useMemo, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  
  const myObj = useMemo(() => ({current: 0}), [])
  const myRef = useRef(0)

  useEffect(() => {
    myObj.current = myObj.current + 1;
    myRef.current = myRef.current + 1;
  })

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Increase Count Number </button>
      <span>{myObj.current}</span>
      <span>{myRef.current}</span>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically both can be interchanged as far as the dependency array is empty for `useMemo`. But if you want to recalculate the value based on a certain prop or state variable change you can use useMemo by putting them in the dependency array

Technically same expressions

```
const ref = useRef(computeExpensiveValue(a, b));

const memoizedValue = useMemo(() => computeExpensiveValue(a, b));


// in above - ref.current and memoizedValue will be same
```

But if we want to recalculate the value if `a` or `b` changes then we should `useMemo` like below

```
const memoizedValue = useMemo(() => computeExpensiveValue(a, b), [a, b]);
```

Comment: This isn't true - in the `ref` version, the `computeExpensiveValue` function gets called every time the component rerenders (although its return value is ignored). But that's significant in the case that `computeExpensiveValue` is doing anything CPU intensive.

Answer (score 0):

`useMemo` is intended to memoize the functions that are being called inside its argument function.

The way you're using it, the return value of `useMemo` is equivalent to the one of `useRef`.
However it won't make sense to the next person that'll read it, as this is not the case that `useMemo` is meant to be used in:

1. The **function** has absolutely no reason to be memoized.
2. The **dependency array** is empty, hence the function is only being called once.